# How to write .gitlab-ci.yml job to run only in merge-request is approved

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml, gitlab-ci-trigger

I am checking on a solution where GITLAB CI job has to run only when merge-request is approved.

test_c:
stage: test
script:
- echo "This job tests something. It will only run when all jobs in the"
- echo "build stage are complete."
rules:
- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

This works when the merge request is created but not when it is approved.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the predefined variable

`CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED`

```
rules: 
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED == "true"
```